# Polymer 0.8: Data binding inside a HTML tag complex attribute

Tags: html, data-binding, polymer

I understood that in the newer Polymer release 0.8 binding to an attribute inside a tag should be followed after $ sign. And it works like so:

```
<tag attribute$="{{DATA}}">
```

e.g. this works great:

```
href$="{{url}}"
```

But it doesn't work when the attribute gets more complex, e.g. in my code example:

```
<a style$="background-image: url({{backgroundimage}});">
```

which is a String data attribute.

Is it supported in 0.8 like it was in 0.5 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complex bindings like that are not currently supported in 0.8. Instead you'd probably want to create [a computed property](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.8/docs/devguide/properties.html#computed-properties) and use that.

Btw, you only need to use `$={{ }}` syntax if you need work with an attribute that doesn't have a corresponding property on an element. Because HTMLAnchorElement (the `<a>` tag) has an `href` property, you don't have to use a dollar sign in that case, you can just create a regular binding using `href={{url}}`.

To put it another way:

> href="{{site}}" means "bind this.site to element.href"
>   href$="{{site}}" means "bind this.site to element.attributes.href.value"

You usually only need the $ syntax when working with boolean attributes like hidden or disabled. Or in the case where an element does not have a corresponding property in JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you I have used Computed property data binding. 
This is the result:

    `<a class="title" href="{{url}}" style$="{{computebackgroundimageurl}}">`

and 

`<script>
Polymer({
    is: "card-concept",

    properties: {
      backgroundimageurl: {
        type: String,
        value: ""
      },
      computebackgroundimageurl: {
        type: String,
        computed: 'computebu(backgroundimageurl)'
      }
    },
   
 computebu: function(backgroundimageurl) {
    return 'background-image: url(' + backgroundimageurl + ');';
 }
 
  });
</script>`